# Is there any way from which we can detect images are loading from cache in picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

as title suggest I want to check whether images are loading from cache or not.

I've done something like this but couldn't succeeded.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(data.get(position).get("product_image"))
                .into(viewHolder.imgViewIcon, new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if (Picasso.LoadedFrom.NETWORK != null)
                            YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(1200)
                                    .playOn(viewHolder.imgViewIcon);
                        viewHolder.placeholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });
```

Please anyone have batter option then tell me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use Picasso's `setIndicatorEnabled(true)` to detect where the image is loaded from.

```
Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(context);
picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);

//...
picasso.load("http://example.com/image.jpg").into(myImageView);
```

[image]

A colored ribbon will appear in the top left corner.

- Red: network
- Yellow: disk
- Green: memory

Source: [Picasso - Debug Indicators](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: +1, hey Marcos, thanks for this awesome answer. it does helped in my other doubt but not in this one. What I was doing, when images has been loaded it appears with animation. but as recycling of `RecyclerView` those images again animated when they recycled. so I used `SparseBooleanArray` for solving that. but Thanks it didi helped in my other problem